# Source Code Editor (IDE) for iOS

Tags: software-development, ide, ios

Many times I opt to take my iPad with me instead of my Macbook Pro.  That being said, I wish I had the ability to still code using my iPad.  I understand that the lack of direct access to the file system in iOS can make this challenging, but can be worked around with technologies that utilize the cloud.

So, do you know of any good IDE apps for iOS that provide much of the basic coding features that we expect like:

- Syntax Coloring
- Syntax Checking
- Code formatting (tabbing, reformatting, refactoring, auto complete, etc.)
- Code hinting & documentation references
- Ability to access files that I have stored in the cloud or on an ftp server.
- A huge plus would be its ability to check out files from a repo (GIT or SVN) and provide basic check-in and update functionality as the user works on said files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try [Textastic Code Editor for iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textastic-code-editor/id383577124?mt=8) (offical [website](http://www.textasticapp.com/)). This is a paid app and is $9 USD.

Some of the app's features:

- Syntax highlighting of more than 80 languages
- Code completion for HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP functions
- Uploads files via FTP, FTPS (FTP over SSL), SFTP (SSH connection), WebDAV, Dropbox, iCloud and email
- Displays additional keys over the virtual keyboard to make it easy to type characters often used for programming
- Auto indentation
- Customizable font and font sizes
- Undo/redo and find/replace
- File information like character count and word count
- Local and remote web preview for html and Markdown files

You can import files through:

- iTunes
- Using "open-in" in other apps
- Connect to (S)FTP and WebDAV servers and Dropbox
- Over Wi-Fi with the built-in WebDAV server

Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: Note that Textastic used to be iPad only, but they released an iPhone version. It's not a universal app though, so you need to purchase it separately. It's $8.99 at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

You could try **[Diet Coda](http://panic.com/dietcoda/)** ($19.99, on the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/diet-coda/id500906297?mt=8&uo=4)), which is an iPad version of Panic's [Coda](http://panic.com/coda/) application for Mac. It has just been updated (to version 1.5) and now supports local file editing.

[image: Diet Coda file edit screen]

The app offers **syntax highlighting** for HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, Python, Ruby, Apache, Diff, Django, ERB, Haml, LESS, Markdown, Perl, and SCSS and works with **remote files** (via FTP or SFTP) and **local files** (via Dropbox). Furthermore an **SSH terminal** is built in (which you could use to work with Git on the server, in your situation).

Answer (score 1):

I've heard that Working Copy ([$14.99](https://appsto.re/us/aEqH5.i), [Free](https://appsto.re/us/xONC1.i)) is a fairly well regarded Git client for iPhone and iPad. It has a free version available, but you'll only be able to save commits locally. You'll need to pay in order to push your commits back to a remote server like GitHub.

[image]